# Unable to insert value in a table column

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have been trying to insert value inside a column like this :

```
insert into schema.table (reason_code) values('5697')
```

Now reason_code is of type `varchar2` and `data_field` length is 4. However when i execute this query i get this error :

`ORA-01400: cannot insert null into ('schema.table.reason_code')`

The reason_code field in DB Visualizer is depicted as :

[image]

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: Is there only one column in tour table? is it primary key?

Comment: There are many columns, i just uploaded the image of the reason_code column and no that's not the primary key .

Comment: There are three other columns which are primary keys for the table.

Comment: @ŁukaszBańcarz What's the id refer to here ? Does that refer to editing via other column values ?

Comment: sorry, haven't seen your last comment... what is your db server MSSQL or MySql?

Comment: Are you sure the error message refers to `reason_code`, not one of the columns in the PK - wondering if you inadvertently changed it when masking the `schema.table` part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are making INSERT into a row please make sure that you put values in all NOT NULL columns.
`INSERT INTO schema.table1 (non_null_column1,non_null_column2) VALUES (1,2) ;`

After this statement remaining columns in the table will be NULLed.

If you have another non null column in this table however, you will receive ORA-01400 error.